# Fail to update/upgrade Oh-My-Zsh package with `sudo pacman -S Oh-My-Zsh` command

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to update/upgrade the oh-my-zsh package in my arch linux using the zsh terminal.  Usually, I can update a package with this command `sudo pacman -S package-name`.  But, it does not work with Oh-My-Zsh.  Instead, I found out that I have to use this command `upgrade_oh_my_zsh`. Can anyone shed some light into this matter?

Edit: Specifically, I would like to know why `sudo pacman -S package-name` does not work on Oh-My-Zsh? Why do I have to use `upgrade_oh_my_zsh` to upgrade it? Is there no standard command for updating/upgrading a package? As a new Arch Linux user, this is confusing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

As far as I remember oh-my-zsh is not available as an official package. It's in the aur (arch user repository) with the name [oh-my-zsh-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/oh-my-zsh-git/)

To install/update that you need to use `pacaur` or `yaourt` but **not** `pacman`!

Btw last updated: `2016-06-26 12:03`

---

Oh-My-Zsh asks for updating itself from time to time, doesn't it?

You can update it manually in `~/.oh-my-zsh/`

```
 git pull --rebase --stat origin master
```

If you get a

> Cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes

Do a `git stash` and try the `pull` again.

Thanks to **@Adaephon** to point out to do a

```
git stash pop
```

afterwards to to re-apply the stashed changes

Comment: After `pull` you may want to do `git stash pop` to re-apply the changes you previously made. Unless one of your changes directly conflicts with something you updated, this should "just work".

Comment: Thanks guys, I am sure the method that you suggested would work. But, I am more concerned about the standard method of upgrading/updating the Oh-My-Zsh package. Please see the edited section of my question above.

Comment: @goddar I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @MichaelD. I can see now that the package is from AUR and I would understand it if I have to use this command: `yaourt -S <package>`.  However, what I found on google search was to use 'upgrade_oh_my_zsh'. Can I update other packages with upgrade_package-name?

Comment: Try the arch linux wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers